# How to find connected cells with same value in an array

Tags: c, arrays

Basically, I'm trying to take an already existing 50 x 50 2-D array of numbers, and using the origin given in the code already (iy and ix), to use to find connected cells with the same value and replace all non-connected cells to 0. An example is an array such as

```
1 5 3 2 5 5 5
0 1 9 4 5 0 0
3 3 4 5 5 5 5
```

Using the cell at (1,4), I would then get an array of

```
0 0 0 0 5 5 5
0 0 0 0 5 0 0
0 0 0 5 5 5 5
```

My current code just finds all cells with equal height, it doesn't do anything to find the connected ones. It just doesn't clean it up, per se. I think it's an issue with how im going through the list in the for loops to check for connected cells, but I cant tell what the issue is

I'm coding this using C. Any help would be appreciated!

```
//Get the "height" of the "origin" cell
int height = array[x][y];

//I copy the original array into the new array, 
//but I only copy the cells with values equal to the "height" of the first cell

    for (int i = 0; i <= 50; i++)
    {
      for (int j = 0; j <= 50; j++)
      {
        if (array[i][j] == height)
        {
          newarray[i][j] = array[i][j];
        }
        else
        {
          newarray[i][j] = 0;
        }
      }
    }

// Iterate through the array, starting from the origin cell. 
//If the cell above or to the left isn't connected to it, then turns it into a 0 cell
    for (int i = x; i <= 50; i++)
    {
      for (int j = y; j <= 50; j++)
      {
        if (newarray[i][j] == height)
        {
          if (newarray[i][j-1] == height || newarray[i-1][j] == height)
          {
            newarray[i][j] = height;
          }
          else
          {
            newarray[i][j] = 0;
          }
        }
      }
    }

//Does the same, but does it towards the origin (0,0). If the cell to the right 
//or below isnt connected to it then it turns it into a 0 cell
    for (int i = x; i >= 0; i--)
    {
      for (int j = y; j >= 0; j--)
      {
        if (array[i][j] == height)
        {
          if (newarray[i][j+1] == height || newarray[i+1][j] == height)
          {
            newarray[i][j] = height;
          }
          else
          {
            newarray[i][j] = 0;
          }
        }
      }
    }


}
```

EDIT:

I have a potential recursive solution to the issue as well, but I get a segmentation fault when I try to run it

```
void connectedvals(char array[50][50], char newarray[50][50], int x, int y)
{

int height = array[x][y];
    newarray[x][y] = array[x][y];
    int up = y + 1;
    int down = y - 1;
    int left = x - 1;
    int right = x + 1;

    if (up < 50)
    {
      if (array[x][up] == height)
      {
        newarray[x][up] = height;
        up++;
        connectedvals(array, newarray, x, up)
      }
    }

    if (down >= 0)
    {
      if (array[x][down] == height)
      {
        newarray[x][down] = height;
        down--;
        connectedvals(array, newarray, x, down)
      }
    }

    if (right < 50)
    {
      if (array[right][y] == height)
      {
        newarray[right][y] = height;
        right++;
        connectedvals(array, newarray, right, y)
      }
    }

    if (left >= 0)
    {
      if (array[left][y] == height)
      {
        newarray[left][y] = height;
        left--;
        connectedvals(array, newarray, left, y)
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Suppose the `9` were replaced by a `5`; would that be connected to the other `5`'s?  Do diagonal connections count, or only horizontal and vertical ones?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Diagonal connections don't count in this function. The only way a number can be connected is from upwards, downwards, left or right :)

Comment: One of the ways of doing the search is with a recursive function that is passed a given location, and then looks in each of the four directions to see if it (a) has visited that direction before (in which case, it ignores it), or (b) whether that cell needs searching from because it matches too.  This gradually adds data to the new array.  If the new array is all zero to start and you're looking for some non-zero value, then it isn't hard to get the ball rolling and yet tell where you've visited.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I've tried solving this recursively multiple different ways, but since the array is so large I always get a segmentation fault that I don't know how to solve.

Comment: 50x50 is not a large array.  I dunno what you're doing wrong in your recursive solution, but it shouldn't cause a problem.  You have to check for edges, of course, to ensure you don't go out of bounds, but it be surprising to run out of stack even with 2500 levels of recursion — one per cell in a 50x50 matrix.  If you show the recursive solution, we can probably help you fix it.  I'm not sure how you're going to make your current proposal work, though.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I added my recursive solution. If you can see what's wrong with it and could help fix that would be much appreciated.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I added the header for the function

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Sorry, my bad for the "if left >= 0 50" It was a typo and has been fixed. I haven't come across #define or enum as I'm just starting to learn C and this was just a problem I found online that I thought would be a fun challenge to take on. I also changed the range to be strictly less than 50, but the function still gives me a segmentation fault

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of problems with the recursive solution, including:

1. You don't pass the search value to the recursive function, so different recursive calls can end up looking for different values.
2. You don't check whether you've already visited a given cell, so the recursion doesn't stop.

Here are two versions of the code that don't crash.

#### `conn29.c` — minimally fixed

This code fixes point 2, and the result demonstrates point 1.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

enum { SIZE = 13 };

static
void connectedvals(char array[SIZE][SIZE], char newarray[SIZE][SIZE], int x, int y)
{
    if (newarray[x][y] != 0)
        return;
    int height = array[x][y];
    newarray[x][y] = array[x][y];
    int up = y + 1;
    int down = y - 1;
    int left = x - 1;
    int right = x + 1;

    if (up < SIZE)
    {
        if (array[x][up] == height)
        {
            newarray[x][up] = height;
            up++;
            connectedvals(array, newarray, x, up);
        }
    }

    if (down >= 0)
    {
        if (array[x][down] == height)
        {
            newarray[x][down] = height;
            down--;
            connectedvals(array, newarray, x, down);
        }
    }

    if (right < SIZE)
    {
        if (array[right][y] == height)
        {
            newarray[right][y] = height;
            right++;
            connectedvals(array, newarray, right, y);
        }
    }

    if (left >= 0)
    {
        if (array[left][y] == height)
        {
            newarray[left][y] = height;
            left--;
            connectedvals(array, newarray, left, y);
        }
    }
}


static void dump_array(const char *tag, int rows, int cols, char array[rows][cols])
{
    printf("%s (%dx%d):\n", tag, rows, cols);
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        {
            putchar(' ');
            if (array[i][j] == 0)
                putchar('.');
            else
                printf("%d", array[i][j]);
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    char base[SIZE][SIZE] = { 0 };
    char trace[SIZE][SIZE] = { 0 };

    // srand(time(0));
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
        {
            base[i][j] = (rand() % 12);
            if (base[i][j] > 9)
                base[i][j] = 0;
            if ((rand() % 4) == 0)
                base[i][j] = 5;
        }
    }

    dump_array("Base array", SIZE, SIZE, base);

    int i0 = rand() % SIZE;
    int j0 = rand() % SIZE;

    while (base[i0][j0] != 5)
    {
        i0 = rand() % SIZE;
        j0 = rand() % SIZE;
    }

    printf("i0 = %2d, j0 = %2d, base[%2d][%2d] = %d\n", i0, j0, i0, j0, base[i0][j0]);

    connectedvals(base, trace, i0, j0);

    dump_array("Connected region", SIZE, SIZE, trace);

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
Base array (13x13):
 7 5 5 . . . . 3 7 5 3 9 4
 3 8 1 8 2 7 3 5 5 5 8 6 5
 5 4 5 6 . 5 5 5 . . 7 9 5
 5 3 9 5 5 3 . 5 . 4 5 9 5
 5 1 5 5 5 3 . 5 . 5 5 5 .
 . 5 7 5 3 2 2 4 8 . 8 3 6
 5 1 3 5 6 5 . 2 7 4 2 7 1
 8 . 4 5 5 7 9 . 5 . 5 . 7
 5 9 5 2 . 1 5 5 3 . . 5 5
 . 7 1 8 3 3 5 9 . . 3 3 3
 . 5 1 5 9 9 5 8 5 2 5 . 8
 4 2 9 9 . 5 5 5 . 5 2 4 3
 5 2 5 2 3 5 4 1 5 9 5 5 5
i0 =  5, j0 =  3, base[ 5][ 3] = 5
Connected region (13x13):
 . . . . . . . . . . . . .
 . . . . . . . . . . . . .
 . . . . . . . . . . . . .
 . . . 5 5 3 . . . . . . .
 . . . 5 . 3 . . . . . . .
 . . . 5 . 2 2 4 . . . . .
 . . . 5 . . . . . . . . .
 . . . 5 5 7 . . . . . . .
 . . . . . . . . . . . . .
 . . . . . . . . . . . . .
 . . . . . . . . . . . . .
 . . . . . . . . . . . . .
 . . . . . . . . . . . . .
```

#### `conn11.c` — fixed fully

There is probably some room for improvement still, but this works.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

enum { SIZE = 13 };

extern void connectedvals(char array[SIZE][SIZE], char newarray[SIZE][SIZE], int x, int y, int value);

void connectedvals(char array[SIZE][SIZE], char newarray[SIZE][SIZE], int x, int y, int value)
{
    /*printf("a[%2d][%2d] = %d\n", x, y, array[x][y]);*/
    if (array[x][y] != value || newarray[x][y] != 0)
        return;
    newarray[x][y] = value;

    if (y + 1 < SIZE)
        connectedvals(array, newarray, x + 0, y + 1, value);
    if (y - 1 >= 0)
        connectedvals(array, newarray, x + 0, y - 1, value);
    if (x + 1 < SIZE)
        connectedvals(array, newarray, x + 1, y + 0, value);
    if (x - 1 >= 0)
        connectedvals(array, newarray, x - 1, y + 0, value);
}

static void dump_array(const char *tag, int rows, int cols, char array[rows][cols])
{
    printf("%s (%dx%d):\n", tag, rows, cols);
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        {
            putchar(' ');
            if (array[i][j] == 0)
                putchar('.');
            else
                printf("%d", array[i][j]);
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    char base[SIZE][SIZE] = { 0 };
    char trace[SIZE][SIZE] = { 0 };

    // srand(time(0));
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
        {
            base[i][j] = (rand() % 12);
            if (base[i][j] > 9)
                base[i][j] = 0;
            if ((rand() % 4) == 0)
                base[i][j] = 5;
        }
    }

    dump_array("Base array", SIZE, SIZE, base);

    int i0 = rand() % SIZE;
    int j0 = rand() % SIZE;

    while (base[i0][j0] != 5)
    {
        i0 = rand() % SIZE;
        j0 = rand() % SIZE;
    }

    printf("i0 = %2d, j0 = %2d, base[%2d][%2d] = %d\n", i0, j0, i0, j0, base[i0][j0]);

    connectedvals(base, trace, i0, j0, base[i0][j0]);

    dump_array("Connected region", SIZE, SIZE, trace);

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
Base array (13x13):
 7 5 5 . . . . 3 7 5 3 9 4
 3 8 1 8 2 7 3 5 5 5 8 6 5
 5 4 5 6 . 5 5 5 . . 7 9 5
 5 3 9 5 5 3 . 5 . 4 5 9 5
 5 1 5 5 5 3 . 5 . 5 5 5 .
 . 5 7 5 3 2 2 4 8 . 8 3 6
 5 1 3 5 6 5 . 2 7 4 2 7 1
 8 . 4 5 5 7 9 . 5 . 5 . 7
 5 9 5 2 . 1 5 5 3 . . 5 5
 . 7 1 8 3 3 5 9 . . 3 3 3
 . 5 1 5 9 9 5 8 5 2 5 . 8
 4 2 9 9 . 5 5 5 . 5 2 4 3
 5 2 5 2 3 5 4 1 5 9 5 5 5
i0 =  5, j0 =  3, base[ 5][ 3] = 5
Connected region (13x13):
 . . . . . . . . . . . . .
 . . . . . . . . . . . . .
 . . . . . . . . . . . . .
 . . . 5 5 . . . . . . . .
 . . 5 5 5 . . . . . . . .
 . . . 5 . . . . . . . . .
 . . . 5 . . . . . . . . .
 . . . 5 5 . . . . . . . .
 . . . . . . . . . . . . .
 . . . . . . . . . . . . .
 . . . . . . . . . . . . .
 . . . . . . . . . . . . .
 . . . . . . . . . . . . .
```

The test harness is almost identical between the two programs.  The difference is in the argument list for the initial call to `connectedvals()` because the two implementations have different numbers of arguments.

The choice of `13` for size is not accidental; it happens to produce a neat result with the random number generator.  The matrix is generated 'at random', except that the result is skewed deliberately towards the numbers 0 and 5.  You may well get a different result from the `rand()` function on your machine; I was testing on a MacBook Pro running macOS 10.14.5 Mojave, using GCC 9.1.0 to compile.

There is provision for using the time as a seed — uncommenting one line.  For initial testing, though, determinacy (repeatability) is more beneficial than randomness.  There are many better ways of seeding `rand()` than using the time; that is rather predictable.  However, such refinements are out of scope for the question.

Note the use of the `enum { SIZE = 13 };`.  By changing just the one number, the whole program adapts to new sizes.